# Should I delete the pointer in this case?

Tags: c++

In my own string class(just for learning) i have overload of operator +
Do I need to clean the memory pointed by `tmpPtr`?

```
String String::operator+(const String& rv) const
{
    size_t newLength = length + rv.length;
    char* tmpPtr = new char[newLength + 1];
    strcpy(tmpPtr, ptr);
    strcpy(tmpPtr + length, rv.ptr);
    String S(tmpPtr);
    delete[] tmpPtr;
    return S;
}
```

Can i change this method this way?

```
String String::operator+(const String& rv) const
{
    size_t newLength = length + rv.length;
    char* tmpPtr = new char[newLength + 1];
    strcpy(tmpPtr, ptr);
    strcpy(tmpPtr + length, rv.ptr);
    return S(tmpPtr);
}
```

If someone needs a constructor and a destructor:

```
String::String(const char* str)
{
    setString(str, strlen(str));
}

String::String(const String& str)
{
    setString(str.ptr, str.length);
}
void String::setString(const char* str, size_t size)
{
    ptr = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(ptr, str);
    length = size;
}
String::~String()
{
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

Comment: That depends, can you show us the constructor for your String class? (I assume it's an exercise)

Comment: @EdHeal looking at the code, OP is probably learning c++ and is trying to implement a String class as an exercise.

Comment: Tip: Consider overloading `+=` as a member function, and use that to define `+` as a non-member. Also read: [Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) Also, this GOTW article should be interesting: [Monoliths "Unstrung"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum For you

Comment: @OrangeFox in that case, yes, you should delete that string. Or better, don't perform two allocations.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum _Or better, don't perform two allocations_.Please explain what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

As Vlad says, it depends on how you implement the constructor.

If your constructor simply takes ownership of the pointer and then deletes it in the destructor, you do not need a `delete[]` here.  However, this is problematic, as it means that you cannot safely construct a `String` instance directly from a string literal.

Usually, a better way to write the constructor is to copy the contents of the passed-in pointer to a new block of memory and then store a pointer to that.  This means that the memory usage of `String` is symmetric: it deallocates everything it allocates, and nothing else.  This means that if you `new[]` something and then pass that pointer to your `String`'s constructor, you still need to `delete[]` it.

However, whichever way it is, neither option is a particularly good fit here.  Instead, you should do something like this:

```
String String::operator+(const String& rv) const
{
    size_t newLength = length + rv.length;
    // Create a string with enough backing storage
    String S(newLength + 1);
    strcpy(S.ptr, ptr);
    strcpy(S.Ptr + length, rv.ptr);
    return S;
}
```

This makes sure that it is the `String` instance managing the memory involved, so you get all the clean-up guarantees you normally get from a constructor/destructor pair.

**Edit**: With the body of the constructor available we can conclude that you took the second approach.  Therefore, if you keep using this approach, you **do** need to `delete[]` the memory.

Comment: `String S(newLength + 1);`Do you want to say that I need to make a constructor that takes a string size?

Comment: @OrangeFox yes, that what he is saying. The constructor should allocate the backing storage and the destructor should release it. That way ownership is clear.

Comment: @OrangeFox: Yes, you should.  An interesting question is whether you take the length or the length + 1.  I'd do the former if your length constructor is going to be public.  If it's an implementation detail, you're free to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In general, you need to delete the memory allocated by `new`.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(C%2B%2B)) says:

> In the C++ programming language, the `delete` operator calls the destructor of the given argument, and returns memory allocated by `new` back to the heap.[1] A call to `delete` must be made for every call to `new` to avoid a memory leak.

#### C++11: 3.8 Object lifetime (p4):

> ..... if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a *delete-expression* (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

---

**EDIT**: As per the OP's edit, as your destructor is deallocating the memory, **in this case no need to delete the `ptr` explicitly**. But still need to delete `tmpPtr` using `delete[]` operator.

Comment: It's impossible to tell given the code OP has provided.

Comment: this is a general guideline - whenever you define a `new` somewhere you should use a `delete` on the memory you've allocated.

Comment: The String class might take ownership of it. It's not clear from the question.

Comment: @isarandi; See the edited [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23980132/2455888). I am talking in general sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `String::setString` member function which is invoked by the constructor `String::String` creates its own char array in dynamic memory and copies the contents of the passed string there:

```
void String::setString(const char* str, size_t size)
{
    ptr = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(ptr, str);
    length = size;
}
```

The originally created memory in `String::operator+` is no longer required, is stored nowhere and will therefore leak if not deleted. So, yes, you have to `delete[]` it.